# INNER JOIN ON IF Statement?

Tags: mysql, join

In Access I have a query that uses an Inner Join with and IF statement. Can I use this in MySQL or not as it doesn't seem to work as intended, not sure if there's something missing or if MySQL doesn't allow the method?

```
SELECT Matrix.Model, Payment.Cost 
FROM Payment
INNER JOIN Matrix ON if(Left(Matrix.Model,1)='S', Left(Matrix.Model,2), Left(Matrix.Model,1) = Matrix.PreFix)
GROUP BY Matrix.Model
```

I seem to get everything returned that doesn't start with an S as though the method isn't valid but not causing a major error.

Comment: Try these links, may be its help you..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640321/conditional-inner-join-statements-in-mysql ...... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585338/mysql-inner-join-if-statement ........ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038322/how-to-choose-inner-join-field-with-if-case

Comment: I think you just have your closing bracket in the wrong place. You are doing a join  based on either _Left(Matrix.Model,2)_ evaluating to true or _Left(Matrix.Model,1) = Matrix.PreFix_ evaluating to true, depending on the value of _Left(Matrix.Model,1)='S'_ . Move the closing bracket from the end of the join condition to before the equals sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query (using table aliases to make it more readable):

```
SELECT m.Model, p.Cost 
FROM Payment p INNER JOIN
     Matrix m
     ON if(Left(m.Model,1) = 'S', Left(m.Model, 2), Left(m.Model, 1) = m.PreFix)
GROUP BY m.Model;
```

Note that there are two possible returns from this statement:  `Left(m.Model, 2)` and `Left(m.Model, 1) = m.PreFix`.  This is a numeric context, so the `then` clause is interpreted as a number.  Strings that start with non-numeric characters (such as `S`) are converted to `0`, which is false.

I would write this without the `if()`:

```
SELECT m.Model, p.Cost 
FROM Payment p INNER JOIN
     Matrix m
     ON (m.model like 'S%' and m.Prefix = Left(m.Model, 2)) or
        (m.model not like 'S%' and m.Prefix = Left(m.Model, 1))
GROUP BY m.Model;
```

Also, the column `p.cost` will be a value from an indeterminate row -- it is neither in the `group by` nor is it in an aggregation function.  This construct would not work in any other database.  It uses an extension to MySQL, whose use is generally discouraged unless you really understand what you are doing.

Comment: Superb, Thank you Gordon - this worked like a charm. A different method to the way Access works but still very understandable for the newbie. Ta